# Multiple `new Vue()` Vue global instances using the same sub-component names. Possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a single HTML file I have two `new Vue()` global Vue instances:

- `new Vue({ el: "#normal-view" })` and,
- `new Vue({ el: "#xrays-view" })`,

And I want to show a different template for each view **using the same component name**. For example:

- `Vue.component('head', { template: "I see a eyes and skin" })` and `Vue.component('head', { template: "I see a skull" })`,
- `Vue.component('wrist', { template: "I see fingers" })` and `Vue.component('wrist', { template: "I see bones" })`
- and so on.

How can I make each `new Vue()` instance read the correct set of `Vue.components` while **keeping them global** (created with `Vue.component()`) and with exactly the same names on them? Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need to register them globally if they are supposed to be scoped to the specific context anyways? This looks much more like a requirement issue than a technical one.

Comment: @TommyF Because components are nested multiple levels and the content is almost the same except for a few changes.